# How can I use in a app with wicket some dynamic feedback panel?

Tags: java, wicket, feedback

I have a java app with wicket and I would need to display in a feedback panel something like a status of the things being processed. Using the default usage of the feedback panel, I see only the final result, although I use inside a for something like

```
for (int agency = START_AGENCY; TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_AGENTIES >= agency; agency++) {
  for (String cont : getsContOutFromFormula(formula)) {
    ......
    message = agency + ": " + cont + " - " + val;
    info(message);
  }
}
```

Does the feedback panel permits something like this?Or how can I display something like a log on a web page - step by step?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how HTTP works - you make a request, it is processed and a response is written back to the browser.

info() just adds feedback messages which will be written in the response. But the response is sent to the browser only once the processing is finished fully.

If you want to sent chunks in the response then you need to use WebSocket communication instead of Ajax requests.